# Aggregation by two columns, excel. power query

Tags: excel, aggregate, powerquery, m

I have a dataframe like this

| idvac | idcand | event | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | call | yes |
| 1 | 1 | meeting | no |

I'd like to get like this

```
idvac idcand call  meeting
 1       1   yes     no
```

seems like the best solution is Pivot columns (Power Query), but there I can get just

```
idvac idcand call  meeting
  1      1    yes   null
  1      1    null  no
```

how to solve it?

P.S. Sorry, I haven't been here for a long time, I hope I formatted the post correctly

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Did any answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for that answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 1):

I get this using pivot:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"idvac", Int64.Type}, {"idcand", Int64.Type}, {"event", type text}, {"status", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[event]), "event", "status")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your data is set up

In powerquery, you get this when pivoting

[image]

only if idvac and idcand are **exactly** the same for the two rows

If one is numerical, or contains a space, and the other is alpha, or any other dissimilarity, when you pivot you get you get

[image]

So you need to make them the same before the pivot that Davide is showing in his answer

Comment: Good spot and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just copied the 4 cells and using paste.special transpose got the result below:

[image]